# Arranging text using javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tree

I have an array of objects which are (Sequences) stored as an array in javascript as

array = [ A, G, G, A, G, A, A, G, G, G, A, A, G, G ]

How do I design an algoritm and implement in javascript so that they go to postions as shown in the image below.

[image]

Say placeAtTop('A') will place A at the top
Say placeAtBottom('G') will place G at the bottom

Whenever A is encountered from left to right it should go to placeAtTop() and whenever G is parsed it should be placeAtBottom() from left to right sequentially.

**EDIT:**

The expected output is the callof functions

```
// create new page

placeAtTop('A')
placeAtBottom('G')
placeAtBottom('G')

// create new page

placeAtTop('A')
placeAtBottom('G')

// create new page

placeAtTop('A')

// create new page

placeAtTop('A')
placeAtBottom('G')
placeAtBottom('G')
placeAtBottom('G')

// create new page

placeAtTop('A')

// create new page

placeAtTop('A')
placeAtBottom('G')
placeAtBottom('G')
```

Comment: And what is problem with your code?

Comment: And what exactly is your output target? A data structure of some kind, or HTML on the page? if the latter provide your existing HTML. Also, please include what you have attempted so far

Comment: Is it always only 2 different characters? Or can it be more?

Comment: I have edited the question with expected output described

Comment: So you're saying you can just iterate over the array and use an IF funciton, `array.forEach(i => { if (i == A) { create new page; placeAtTop('A');} else {placeAtBottom('G')} })`

Comment: It's unclear what that output even is. Is that output a string? Is that javascript? `create new page` doesn't look like javascript to me.

Comment: I like when figuring out what exactly is wanted is more time consuming and complex than the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps, algorithmically:

- create a new array, let's just call it `newArray`, which will be 2-dimensional
- iterate over first array

  - for each item in the array, if it's A, make a new Array, push A onto it, and add it to newArray
  - if it's G, push it onto the last subArray of newArray

This would end up with an array that looks like

```
[[A, G, G], [A, G], [A],[A, G, G, G] [A] [A, G, G]]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is is an option to use a regex, capture the groups, loop the groups and then per group loop the letters.
the first letter will be the 'A' and the rest will be a 'G'

For example:

```js
var values = [ 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G' ];
var str = values.join('');
var regex = /(AG*)+?/g;
var groups = str.match(regex);
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    // the groups[i] contains [A,G,G] etc..
    for (var j = 0; j < groups[i].length; j++) {
        if (j === 0) {
            console.log("placeAtTop(" +groups[i][j] + ");")
        } else {
            console.log("placeAtBottom(" +groups[i][j] + ");")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that you have literally output the function calls as text, which is the only thing you can really take from such a poorly described question.

Answer (score 2):

You could create array of arrays based on `A` and then add them to table where each first element will be `A` and you add them to `thead` and other elements are `G` and you add them to `tbody`.

```js
var arr = ["A", "G", "G", "A", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G"]

var i = 0
var r = arr.reduce(function(r, e, j) {
  if (e == 'A' && j != 0) i++;
  if (!r[i]) r[i] = []
  r[i].push(e)
  return r;
}, [])

var thead = document.querySelector('thead tr');
var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody tr');

r.forEach(function(e, i) {
  thead.innerHTML += '<th>' + e[0] + '</th>';
  tbody.innerHTML += '<td>' + e.slice(1).map(e => e + '<br>').join('') + '</td>';
})
```

```css
td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which returns the last array fopr inserting `'A'` following letters.

```js
var array = ['A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G'],
    result = [];
    
array.reduce(function (r, a) {
    if (a === 'A') {
        r = [a];
        result.push(r);
    } else {
        r.push(a);
    }
    return r;
}, null);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```